# Uploading shapefile to PostGIS using GeoPandas

Tags: python, postgis, shapefile, geopandas

I came up with the code to upload my shapefile to PostGIS table. However, my Linux system is not able to install the GeoPandas module. I tried a lot of procedures but no result. So, is there any alternative for `gpd.read_file(shp_file_path)` ?

```
polydf = gpd.read_file(shp_file_path)
polydf.to_postgis('table_name', engine, schema='public', if_exists='append', index=True, index_label='Index')
```

Comment: @BERA  do have gdal, if that's what u mean

Comment: @BERA Actually I want to use python for this purpose. Can you suggest something for that ?

Comment: Pick one of those procedures and provide details of your attempt.

Comment: You are asking for an alternative for reading a shape into python **and** write the results to postgis?

Comment: @BERA Yes that is what I am required to do. My python environment is not able to read GeoPandas package.